# How can I use a list as a function parameter with LuaJ?

Tags: java, lua, luaj

So, I have a function in a Lua script that takes an parameter.

```lua
testFunction = function(listIn)
    for i, obj in ipairs(listIn) do
        print(i)
    end
end
```

This parameter is obviously meant to be a list of objects, but I simply cannot figure out how to pass this parameter in.

I use an interface for the script, so it would look something like this:

```java
public interface LuaScript {
    void testFunction(List<?> listIn);
}
```

This is then called, and that part works fine, it's just that when it comes to the lua interpretation, it throws a `LuaError`, giving the message "bad argument: table expected, got userdata".

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a `List<?>`, pass it a `LuaTable`. [`LuaTable#listOf(LuaValue[])`](http://luaj.org/luaj/3.0/api/org/luaj/vm2/LuaValue.html#listOf(org.luaj.vm2.LuaValue%5B%5D)) will be helpful in converting the former to the latter.